# Create dummy Network to connect to when no WiFi or LAN available

Tags: windows, networking, dns, network-interface, virtual-network

I do a lot of web development. Naturally I use my notebook on the go and there isn't always a WiFi hotspot or LAN available. I would still make use of my custom DNS Server (installed locally) on my Windows notebook for wildcard domain names (*.dev.local). This only works if I am connected to a network of some sort. So is it possible to create a dummy Network without internet connection for which I can set the DNS Server address to localhost?

OS: Windows 10 Pro

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use 127.0.0.1 for your server address.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use your loopback interface address as DNS server address OR you may set a static IP to your physical interface and use the same.